# Use a custom filter with a controller

Tags: angularjs

I've created a filter that checks the user id and then filters out all results in a ng-repeat that don't have that user id.

If I place my filter,

```
UserService.getCurrentUser()
  .then(function(user_id){
    $scope.user_id = user_id;
});
```

In my controller it works fine, but I want to keep my controller as clean as possible so I want to move it out.

I created a file called "userFilter.js" and this is the code,

```
angular.module('addMovieseat', [])

  .filter('user_filter', function() {
    UserService.getCurrentUser()
      .then(function(user_id){
        $scope.user_id = user_id;
    });
  });
```

But when I inject the filter into my controller I get an error,

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: user_filterProvider <- user_filter <- addMovieCtrl`

Also this is my service where I get my current user id,

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

  angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .factory('UserService', function($http, $q){
    return{
      getCurrentUser: function(){
        var user_id = null,

        deferred = $q.defer();
        // Get the current user id and use it to filter out all movies that do not correspond to that id in the main overview.
        $http.get(('/users.json'),{ cache: true}).
          success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            if (status == 200) {
               deferred.resolve(data.id);
            } else {
              deferred.resolve(false);
              console.error('Error happened while getting the user list.')
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: There is no `$scope` in a filter. Why are you using `filter` for this in the first place? Show the code for `getCurrentUser()`. Also a filter needs to return a function that in turn returns the result of the function. Your filter returns nothing

Comment: I'm using a filter because I need to filter out all the results that do not correspond to the current users ID. I can't do this in my RoR backend because for a different feature I need to show all results. That's why I'm filtering in Angular. Also I've added the service.

Comment: if all you want is a filtered list why not just use plain $filter or just array.filter

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon probably because I'm learning Angular and making some mistakes.

Comment: yea no, sorry i didn't mean to critisize i just thought you might have a data reason, just trying to undetstan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if you might be better served using `ng-if` on your repeated items. Like this

```
<li ng-repeat="movie in movies" ng-if="movie.user_id == user_id"></li>
```

Assuming `$scope.user_id` in your controller is the id being checked for, and your list of movies is an array. Like this:

```
$scope.user_id = 'Tim';

$scope.movies = [
    {name: 'Movie Title 1', user_id: 'Tim'},
    {name: 'Movie Title 2', user_id: 'Jane'},
    {name: 'Movie Title 3', user_id: 'Bob'}
];
```

This will only render the movie with user_id 'Tim'.

**EDIT:** [Documentation for `ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

**EDIT 2:** Based on the comment by OP, updated code to reflect specific issue.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do. But I'm not getting it to work. I'll try to explain a bit better. I have a list of movies, every movie has a user_id assigned to it. I'm trying to filter out all the movies that do not correspond to the current user id. Currently I have a scope called `$scope.user_id` which holds the current users id. So I don't understand what the `user.id` is for.

Comment: I updated the answer the reflect your specific variables. If you are still having issues, it might be in the way you fetch the current user_id.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

i actually think what your are looking for is

```
<li ng-repeat="movie in movies|filter:{user_id:user:id}:strict"></li>
```

as shown here 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

using ng-if might lead to weird behavior under certain circunstances make sure you read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf